# How to use Locality Sensitive Hash --LSHKIT

Tags: locality-sensitive-hash

I really need to use LSHKIT for my program to measure the similarity of some high dimensional vectors. there is a library for lsh called lshkit which can be found here: http://lshkit.sourceforge.net/
I am confused to use it. First of all I could not build it so I went to section 3.2 which is "Directly add LSHKIT source to your project"
I put all the src codes in one project and fixed the errors but now I do not know how to use it and compile it for a sample data (which is proposed in the lshkit website)

could you guys please help me to find out how to call the functions and see the results? 
thanks

Comment: After 3 years... Have you found anything? I am looking for the same too :)

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: [this implementation](https://github.com/ekzhu/lsh) of Multi-probe LSH is much easier to use than the C++ library. It also implements LSH Forest.